# When func call in return statement of Pyspark UDF no output returned

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to sort an `ArrayType` col in Pyspark `DataFrame`. 
Following is the pyspark code that is **not giving any output**:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def sort_data_array(row):
    return sorted(row, key=itemgetter(1))
# sorting the ArrayType cols according to ascending order of 1st index elems of inner lists

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1,[[3,2,3], [1,5,4], [5,6,6]]], [2,[[12,3,6], [9,5,1], [5,3,1]]]], StructType([StructField('_1', IntegerType()), StructField('_2', ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))]))
sorting_udf = udf(sort_data_array, ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
df1 = df1.withColumn('sorted_2', sorting_udf(df1['_2']))
df1.take(2)
```

When I make this change **this code runs and gives desired output:**

```
def sort_data_array(row):
    sorted_row = sorted(row, key=itemgetter(1))
    return sorted_row
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: both code sample gives same result.                                                                      [Row(_1=1, _2=[[3, 2, 3], [1, 5, 4], [5, 6, 6]], sorted_2=[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]),
 Row(_1=2, _2=[[12, 3, 6], [9, 5, 1], [5, 3, 1]], sorted_2=[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]])]

Comment: That was due to Integer type being casted as Double in udf output. Please try again now.

Answer (score 0):

Please change index in function,

```
def sort_data_array(row):
    return sorted(row, key=itemgetter(0)) # 0 index
```

Now output is :

```
[Row(_1=1, _2=[[3, 2, 3], [1, 5, 4], [5, 6, 6]], sorted_2=[[1, 5, 4], [3, 2, 3], [5, 6, 6]]), 

Row(_1=2, _2=[[12, 3, 6], [9, 5, 1], [5, 3, 1]], sorted_2=[[5, 3, 1], [9, 5, 1], [12, 3, 6]])]
```